# Diagnostics (perplexity, LogLik, etc) for LDA topic model with textmodel_seededLDA package in R

Tags: r, lda, topicmodels, perplexity

I'm using the `seededLDA` package to do an LDA topic model. However, all of the packages and functions I've found to compute perplexity, log likelihood, exclusivity, etc (and other diagnostic tools) don't work on these models (they only work on `topicmodels` LDA outputs).

I didn't use `topicmodels` because I need to use seed words, and I haven't been able to get the seeding function in `topicmodels` to work.

I really like the look of `topicdoc` but that only works on `topicmodels`. So, does anyone know how to:

- convert the output from `textmodel` into `topicmodels`; OR
- do the diagnostics on `textmodel` outputs?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel